# Custom prop type Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there a way to create custom prop types (and extend it with validation) for Vue.js props?

In the below example you'll find the Object prop `background`. Instead of an Object, I would like to have a custom prop type Image.
Image would check if `src` and `alt` are filled, rest would be optional.

What we have now:

```
export default {
  props: {
    background: {
      type: Object,
      src: String,
      srcset: String,
      alt: String,
      title: String,
    },
  },
};
```

What I'd like to have:

```
class customPropImage {
  // magic ...
}

export default {
  props: {
    background: Image,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure you can do it. According to the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks) you can set the type to the constructor of your custom type. With custom validation it could look something like this:

```
function CustomImage () {
  // Magic
}

Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: {
    myImage: {
      type: CustomImage,
      validator: function (value) {
        return true; // or false based on value of myImage
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here is an [example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9zvpnvmznr)

Comment: Is it possible to write the validation rules in the function as well? Tried it out already, but can't seem to get it working.

Comment: I can write a custom validator next to my custom prop type, obviously. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: From the Vue doc you mentioned :' In addition, type can also be a custom constructor function '. And the example provided there is : `function Person (firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName
  this.lastName = lastName
}` .. Now from the codesandbox in `CustomImage.js`, it has:  `export default class CustomImage {
  constructor(src) { ...... }}` . Without the `constructor` function codesandbox does not show the image whereas in the doc example no such `constructor` function exists though the description there says using such a function.  Can you explain the whole scenario ?

Comment: In the codesandbox, in `App.vue`, it has the `profileImage` attribute inside data. In `blogPost.vue`, it has `<img :src="myImage.src"/>`.  The `myImage` prop inside JS specifies type and validator, supposedly not any value. So how does `myImage.src` get its value ?

Comment: So Vue does not support defining a type for a prop? It is awkward. You have to create a class, manually reassign arguments to fields just to define a type?